# How do I setup one GPIO of raspberry to receive float numbers

Tags: raspberry-pi

So, how do I connect a wire to a gpio on my raspberry and start receiving data, like an int or a float number

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspberry got great documentation for wiring a simple button to the Raspberry Pi GPIO on https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/physical-computing-guide/pull_up_down/

To receive float numbers, you could use the Raspberry SPI peripheral. Mathworks got a great example for creating a digital voltmeter with Raspberry and the MPC3008 Analog to Digital converter on https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/mw/raspberrypiio_product-raspi_build_a_digital_voltmeter-build-a-digital-voltmeter

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention since it's not there yet (or only implicitly in the above answer): For actually reading values you need to use an AD converter, since the RPis GPIOs are digital IOs only. So, you cannot receive more then a high or low signal from them. AD conversion instead will use the I2C-Bus for reading the values comming from the converter.